# How many subgraphs isomorphic to P2 are in Km,n

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

How many subgraphs isomorphic to P2 are in Km,n?

Right now I'm thinking this problem may be either n(m-1) or m(n-1) but I'm not sure how else to think of it. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $P_2$ here is a path of length $2$... i.e. an edge.  How many edges are in $K_{m,n}$?  Well... each edge in $K_{m,n}$ will use a vertex in the one part and a vertex in the other part, and further every choice of pairs of vertices with each vertex in a different part works.  How many choices for the first part?  How many choices in the second part?  Remember what $K_{m,n}$ represents in the first place...

Comment: Yes that's why I was thinking it would be n(m-1). Because there are n choices for the first part of the path and then m-1 choices for the second part of the path. But I guess my question is this right when you take into account that you could have started from the other direction and said there are m choices and then n-1 choices

Comment: No, there are $n$ choices for the vertex in the first part and $m$ choices for the vertex in the second part.

Comment: But then wouldn't you need  n choices for the vertex in the first part and m choices for the vertex in the second part and n-1 choices to make the last part of the path. (My teacher defines a path P2 as having 3 vertices and 2 edges). I was thinking it is (n*m*(n-1))/2 because of double counting or (m*n*(m-1))/2 depending on what side you start on. Are these the same thing?

Comment: Okay, fair enough., I was thinking length in terms of number of vertices, as opposed to number of edges.  If you are looking for the number of paths with two edges, then you have two options, it starts in part A or it starts in part B.  For a path starting in part A, pick which two vertices from A are being used and pick which one vertex from B is used.  Similarly for the other option.  This gives a total of $\binom{m}{2}n + \binom{n}{2}m$